# Polymer element is unregistered

Tags: polymer

I've created an element to display the results of an API call, but it not rendering. I've used the 'unregistered element' bookmarklet from the Polymer team which is showing this as unregistered. I'm using this within the Polymer starter kit.

I'm sure its a simple oversight on my behalf that I'm just not seeing.

The element is is listed in the `elements.html` file and is used in the main index.html file like so.

```
    <section data-route="driver-standings">
      <driver-standing></driver-standing>
    </section>
```

**The element**

```
<dom-module id="driver-standing">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <iron-ajax
          auto
          url="http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/driverStandings.json"
          handle-as="json" 
          last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{driverList}}">
      <span>[[item.Driver.givenName]]</span> <span>[[item.Driver.familyName]]</span>
    <template>

  </template>

  <script>
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    Polymer({
      is: 'driver-standing',

      properties: {
        data: { 
        },
        driverList: {
          computed: 'processDrivers(data)'
        }
      },
      processDrivers: function (data){
        console.log("processDrivers")
        return data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
      }
    });
  })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Any help much appreeciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed the closing `/` on the template tag.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{driverList}}">
  <span>[[item.Driver.givenName]]</span> <span>[[item.Driver.familyName]]</span>
<template>
```

became...

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{driverList}}">
  <span>[[item.Driver.givenName]]</span> <span>[[item.Driver.familyName]]</span>
</template>
```

Easily missed :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `dom-repeat` - template should look some kind of this:

You should have your items you want to display in the item tag and as Polymer goes throw your Array it safes each Object under the name defined under the `as` - tag, so you can access the Object inside of your template binding with the name in curly brackets, like `{{driver}}`

```
<template is="dom-repeat" 
          items="{{driverList}}"
          as="driver">
  <p>{{driver}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: My understanding (and experience) is that each item within the 'loop' is available by default under the name 'item'. I've updated the code snippet to better show the outputting of each object. Adding `as="item"` makes no difference.

Comment: Yes your right, but sometimes you have to add the as - tag! For example when you have nested loops then item won't work because two templates want to write to the item attribute!

Comment: Good to know. I'm sure that will save me a headache in the near future :)